# When is Precise Pangolin being released?

Tags: release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will the upcoming Ubuntu release be made available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65476/when-will-the-upcoming-ubuntu-release-be-made-available)

When is 12.04 "Precise Pangolin" (the next LTS) being released? It has been announced [here](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/784).

Comment: This _has to_ be a duplicate of another question? If it isn't, then it should be edited to be more generally useful.

Comment: @JoErlandSchinstad If someone can find a duplicate that really is a duplicate, then I will gladly vote to close this. :)

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad jrg While there aren't any questions that outline the exact release schedule for 12.04 - there are at least two questions that cover release naming schemes. http://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release and http://askubuntu.com/questions/1233/whats-the-meaning-of-version-numbering-of-ubuntu/1236#1236 I'll let the community decide how they want to handle this.