# Why does Ubuntu release version at x.04 and x.10?

Tags: release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the meaning of version numbering of ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233/whats-the-meaning-of-version-numbering-of-ubuntu)

Why does Ubuntu release at versions x.04 and x.10?

Eg. 10.04, 10.10, 11.04, 11.10, 12.04 etc