# Are X.04 releases generally more stable than X.10 releases?

Tags: version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the meaning of version numbering of ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233/whats-the-meaning-of-version-numbering-of-ubuntu)

I just noticed there are always two versions of Ubuntu, X.04 and X.10. Which is the best? Is it really that X.04 are more stable BUT with less applications?

I have 12.04 and 11.10 but 12.04 keeps logging me off. Should I rather wait for the 12.10?

Please say the differences between a X.04 and a X.10 version.

Comment: In short, the numbering just follows whatever the month Ubuntu was released. If it was released in April, X.04 and if in October, X.10. They don't mean much about stability. Though, by right, 12.04 should be stabler than 11.10 because it is a Long term release and more focus was given on its stability.

Comment: Sure, but is it true that the .04 versions have less apps?

Comment: Not really. The developers decide which apps should become default in each release. And you can always install the apps if you need to after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Well thanks, you really helped me out, all of you guys :D

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 codenamed Precise Pangolin is now the latest stable version of Ubuntu. Also note that Ubuntu releases its each version after considerable testing to make sure it is stable enough for normal use.

So every version whether it is x.04 or x.10 can be considered stable enough for daily usage. Coming to your question, Ubuntu 12.04 is stable. You can use it without worry.

Comment: Neither of the DVs was me, but saying that 12.04 is the "most stable" version could be considered incorrect.  Do I recommend upgrading to it if your hardware supports it?  Sure.  But saying most recent LTS is the *most stable* could be considered incorrect in this case.  I consider 10.04 to be a lot more stable and still under the support cycle even for desktop.

Answer (score 1):

12.04 LTS is the most **recent** version of the system in its long term support (LTS, X.04 numbers) version, which is intended to be more stable than the (pseudo) running releases (X.10 numbers, current one is 11.10?).

The basic difference between the two families is that during their lifecycle, LTS versions only get security fixes, whereas x.10 versions get the upgrades including feature improvements. LTS versions can be viewed as "snaphots" of the features available and stable at the date of their release. Also, LTS versions are released only every 2 years, while .10 versions get a major release every 6 months: stability is the priority in the LTS versions, taking precedence over the ability to stay up-to-date with respect to new features.

However, since the LTS and other major versions are defined by their release date and not by a feature stability evaluation (different policy than Debian, for instance), there is no actual guarantee than 12.04 is "more stable" than 10.04 or than a more recent 12.10. And actually, many people seem to have complained about stability issues or feature regressions since they upgraded to 12.04.

My personal opinion, and it is only an opinion, is that 10.04 (the previous LTS) is *very* stable and reliable. It lacks the most recent versions of the programs, but I observe less problems in production than with 12.04 installations.

Answer (score 1):

12.04.1 LTS is the most stable and recent version. Since 12.10 is still in developement, it cannont be stable. Also, 12.04.1 LTS is a more refined form of 12.04, so it's more stable.

Answer (score 1):

People are dithering around the issue but somebody needs to say this:

- There is no* correlation of stability between and 04/10 releases.
- LTS releases are always 04 but only every other year (8.04, 10.04, 12.04, 14.04, ..).
- LTS doesn't mean* it'll work immediately - it's just supported for longer.

<sub>*****It is *supposed* to be more stable. It's based of a more "stable" Debian release and the targets for the release usually focus more on compatibility and stability than performance or features - but as the last LTS shows, good intentions don't always mean you get what you want.</sub>

<sub>**Edit:** That last sentiment sounds bitter. 12.04 isn't terrible but as you can quickly see from the front page, it's still not without issues.</sub>