# Lubuntu14.10 file server not playing video files

Tags: server, lubuntu, video, samba, vlc

i started off with Lubuntu 13.XX. initially setup the box as a torrent/file server box. for whatever reason, i needed to make changes, and moved to 14.04 but still using the same hardware in the torrent/file server. obtained larger hdd, and decided to update to 14.10 on that drive. everything was working properly for the last 2 weeks without fail until yesterday.

i setup lubuntu with no problem. update/upgrade - no problem. configured samba - no problem. normally use Kodi media player (sometimes VLC) from windows 7 to access lubuntu file server. without warning, it was not able to play some files that i had recently copied to the box. it also stopped playing other files it had always been able to play. i am still able to navigate and view all folders, but the files would not even play with VLC. most files were copy/cut & pasted to the drive via external USB device. i did not think that it should, but is it possible that copy vs cut would affect anything?

the one thing that i did differently was that i ran additional system updates on this box when i had not previously done it under the other configurations. is it possible that new updates broke some file access permissions? naturally i am able to play the videos directly from the lubuntu box itself. i find it strange that files that were recently copied within the same sub folders did not work. for example; season 3 was downloaded and seasons 1&2 were copied from another source, but only season 3 worked since it was originally on lubuntu.

any ideas before i destroy everything and rebuild?

Comment: 1. i am only intending this to be a torrent/file server.

Answer (score 0):

14.10 is a version of Ubuntu with a shorter support period.  Problems are solved more quickly on this version, but it also *has more problems*.  For stability, always choose LTS versions.  See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) for more info.

Furthermore, copy-paste or cut-paste should make no difference, however the *way you remove the USB disk* has an impact.  If you just yank it out without ejecting it, you're going to end up with unreadable files in the long run.

I don't think you have to re-install the system: do a `apt-get purge kodi` and `apt-get install kodi`
OR
try [MiniDLNA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA).

On the other hand, if you *do* decide to re-install, read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) on how to better set up and backup your system, so that if you *do* run into troubles, you're just a restore away from a solution.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: "the staging release version of Ubuntu".   Where's this statement from?  Your assumptions or an actual Ubuntu/Canonical document?

Comment: @ThomasW. Never looked for a document, It was and is obvious for me.  Chat?  General room?

Comment: done - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/discussion-between-fabby-and-thomas-w-regarding-terminology-usage-when-discussin

Comment: for this build, it was only supposed to be a torrent/file server box. i did not install kodi, so purging will not matter. playing from this box was for testing purposes only and not originally intended because i did not include audio support. 

you have raised more questions:
if i were to revert to an (older?) LTS version, would i still have to go through the steps for a full re-install??
is there an option to downgrade to a previous version from within 14.10??
would installing miniDLNA remove the need for samba? 
how does ejecting the external media affect the local internal hdd?

Comment: We're not on the same wavelength then: Can you summarize what your question is in one sentence?