# Lenovo G50 does not switch on WIFi on initial boot or upon resuming system

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, suspend, lenovo

I recently acquired a Lenovo G50, after installing Ubuntu 14.10 (updated to the latest), I could not connect via WiFi. I found a solution that asked me to do `sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop` that only fixed the problem temporarily because whenever I closed the lid of my laptop, I could not connect back to the WIfi when I returned. In fact, I have to restart the machine altogether and run the `sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop` command again, which sort of sucks.

I also found another solution `sudo killall NetworkManager` that worked only a few times.

So I wonder, there must be a solution that.

1. Permanently fix the WiFi, i.e. being able to resume automatically to reconnect
2. Stabilize it such that I do not have to come so close to the router or Internet source

Which are these solutions?

PS: I am relatively new to Ubuntu, I will be happy to answer any questions you may have.

**Edit:** Added the output of `lspci` and `lsusb`:

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 0f23 (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f48 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4c (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4e (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 0f12 (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0461:4d15 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lspci&&lsusb`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question. This will allow us to see what kind of WiFi card you have.

Comment: Hello Fabby, thank you for your response. I have now attached the output of the command to my question. Please check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please review [my edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/582095/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) while I look over your settings...

Comment: If you do a `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` does that solve the problem when closing the lid? (run this command straight after a reboot)

Comment: This is the response I am getting: 

Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

Comment: Then the cannon: go to your BIOS and turn off all power-related settings there.  then boot into Ubuntu and use the following command: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false`  Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. And could that command have created an additional problem? Upon rebooting, I can no longer adjust the brightness of the laptop. We now have two problems.

Comment: Then revert back the BIOS settings and type `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true`.  Unfortunately you have then reached the maximum of my abilities and I will not be able to help you any further...  (also: I'm running 14.01.1 which is more stable then 14.10.  Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) for more info.)

Comment: Fabby, you have tried with all your hear, thank you so much for your help. Lets hope this issue gets restored. 

Yes, brightness control is now back!