# USB, Wifi, audio stopped working on update: Kernel mismatch problems

Tags: networking, wireless, updates, mouse

On my  Lenovo M30-70, Wifi, USB (including mouse), and audio stopped working suddenly. I accepted an incremental update earlier today. (I'm on Utopic.)

I learned that this does not occur if I choose to boot to the last-but-one kernel 3.16.0-29.

However, I don't want to be always booting into what appears to be an older kernel. With the new default kernel, 3.16.0-30, I get these problems. Still, the Ethernet and  the trackpad do work.

Software Updater tells me that I am fully up to date.

What should I do now to revert everything to a stable state or else upgrade to a stable state?

Diagnostics in the buggy state:

*ifconfig*  shows the ethernet and loopback adaptors only, and not the wireless.

*lsusb*

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b420 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

*lspci*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 08)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

*iwconfig* (no stdout outout, only stderr)

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Something got scrambled during transmission, update, or there is an error in the update!
Well is it not wonderfull that our Ubuntu let us get back to a working konfiguration!
Boot into the previous kernel and do the upgrade update from there, that will owervrite whatever error, and you will be up to date again - hopefull without any errors! If the error is persistent try waiting a week for the error to be fixed.
Hope this helps it's saved me a couple of times.
Best of luck!

Comment: Software Updater tells me that the software on my computer is  fully up to date.

Comment: Sorry, Joshua.  That is the problem of 14.10: you're the guinea pig for us 14.04 LTS.  Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) for more info...