# Ubuntu 14.04 & 12.04 on Asus EeeBox PC EB1037 hangs at boot, EB1033 works fine

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, uefi, asus

We're having issues with Asus EeeBox PCs, specifically the EB1037.

We also have the EB1033, but those seem to work without issue.

I believe the main difference is BIOS vs UEFI and better GPU on the EB1033 vs the EB1037.

It seems to freeze at:

```
"EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro"
```

Some research has turned up that it is a display driver issue, and adding

```
"nomodeset"
```

to the kernels boot args will work around the issue and let you see the rest of the boot process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Are you dual-booting? What the contents of `/var/log/dmesg.0` is...  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Well, the computer doesn't seem to boot, so I couldn't have done that. However, I can tell you that I am not dual booting. Doing some research based on a hunch, it seems it's an issue with the Nvidia graphics card and the drivers associated with it. Adding nomodeset to the boot args will fix the issue. Turns out the computer was booting all along, but without display drivers.

Comment: have you tried [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) yet?

Comment: We ended up just running 14.10, which works without issue on this hardware.

Comment: :D OK... Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) then and remember that 14.10 will be out of support in less then a year...

Comment: Yeah, but we needed these things running, like last week, so as long as they work we can always upgrade them later. Still open to answers or solutions though.

Comment: I gave you one: 3 lines up... Did you check that one?