# VDPAU errors in VLC with official nVidia drivers installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, vlc

Playback seems fine until I try seeking the video, then I get this error over and over in the terminal:

```
[00007fba4906ef78] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  343.36  Mon Dec  1 15:53:25 PST 2014 for hardware decoding.
[00007fba4906ef78] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  343.36  Mon Dec  1 15:53:25 PST 2014 for hardware decoding.
video surface destruction failure: The display was pre-empted, or a fatal error occurred.
[00007fba2c000a58] vdpau_avcodec generic error: video surface creation failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fba4906ef78] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
[h264 @ 0x7fba490e0aa0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fba490e0aa0] no frame!
video surface destruction failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fba2c000a58] vdpau_avcodec generic error: video surface creation failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
[00007fba4906ef78] avcodec decoder error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
[h264 @ 0x7fba4913dd80] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fba4913dd80] no frame!
```

This is with a GeForce 970 graphics card.

Comment: Does this happen with all videos or one particular one?

Comment: All videos that I tried, though admittedly I only have h264 videos to try, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried the 346.35 driver yet?  If no, do you have the xorg-edgers PPA installed?

Comment: I checked and I'm using 343.36. But I installed it from the nVidia website, wasn't aware there was a PPA for it.

Comment: No worries...  The PPA just allows an easier upgrade path then the NVidia drivers themselves:  Once you've downloaded and installed those, there is no automatic update: you need to keep an eye on them yourself and update them manually every time NVidia updates them.
What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Ah!  Answer coming up!  (but you're not going to like it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav/+bug/1374825 so the only thing for you to do is to subscribe to the bug list and whenever the bug is resolved, and the update comes in, the problem will go away all by itself...

If you don't want to wait, have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) instead.

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Aha, that looks like it. Totem plays videos just fine so I guess I'll stick with that until it's fixed. Thanks!