# Can I install Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad G505s laptop?

Tags: drivers, laptop, lenovo

So I've checked the Lenovo website and they have no drivers for Ubuntu for this laptop. Only Win 7 and 8. So am I in trouble or is there a way out? I'd assume I need those drivers, right?

Comment: Ubuntu should have support for the laptop itself even if Lenovo doesn't, maybe try live booting and see if everything is working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Lenovo G580 and everything work out the box. Try it. Love it? Install it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: there are no drivers under Ubuntu, only "modules".  These modules serve the same purpose under the Linux kernel (of which Ubuntu is the most common variety) and some people still call them "drivers" because some large company in Redmond, WA calls them that way.

So the easiest thing for you to do would be to have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) and read all the links in the question and read the answer as well.

Then just download the version of Ubuntu which is best for your particular hardware, burn it to DVD, boot it and then click "Try Ubuntu" *without installing it*...  Then you can see for yourself whether it will work (yes!) or not (very improbable)

### Welcome to the world of Ubuntu! ;-)

P.S. If you decide to actually install Ubuntu after trying it, also read ["How to Install software under Ubuntu when you're a Windows User."](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)