# What is an ISO file and how do I use it?

Tags: system-installation, iso

OK, I'm not a techno geek, I just expect my computer to work. Windows hangs up on me too often, and I'm tired of Microsoft for many reasons. So after many recommendations I downloaded Ubuntu. But it came in an ISO file, and I have no idea what to do with it. I also apparently downloaded a 64-bit version although my old laptop has only 2 GB RAM and currently runs 32-bit XP.

So what do I do now/ To me this is like replacing the engine in my own car-- when I barely know more than checking fluids. I just drive it. Help?

Comment: Where did you download it from? I you download it from [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/), you will find directions how to install there. I do not recommend to download from anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

An ISO file is an archive file of an optical disk. If you have a 32-bit machine then you should download the 32-bit version instead. Go [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/572629/364819) for help with which version you should get.

And once you have decided which version to get go to one of these to download the 32-bit version of either:

- [14.04.2 (LTS)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.2&architecture=i386)
- [15.04 (Latest)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=15.04&architecture=i386)

Read this for instructions on how to install the ISO on a LiveCD (USB or disk): [How to burn ISO to disk on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

Once you have burned it onto the LiveCD, then you will need to boot from that disk, to do so, insert the LiveCD and restart the machine. This should take you straight to the Ubuntu installation wizard. If it does not, you will need to enter your machine's BIOS and move the LiveCD to the top of the boot order list, for instructions on how to do this read this: [Boot from CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)

Go here for instructions on the Graphical Installation Wizard: [Graphical Installation Wizard guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

**Duplicate:** [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Download the Ubuntu ISO Trusty Tahr 32 bits from:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

And save to your desktop.

Burn the ISO image to a blank DVD using Nero Burning or similar, option Burn image image to disc.

Or download UNetbootin:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/unetbootin/UNetbootin/608/unetbootin-windows-608.exe?r=http%3A%2F%2Funetbootin.sourceforge.net%2F&ts=1433083494&use_mirror=ufpr

UNetbootin allows for the installation of various Ubuntu distributions to a  USB drive, install al run it and add the ISO using the `Diskimage`, make sure your USB drive is selected below and click OK.

Insert burn DVD or USB, restart your computer and make sure it’s set up to boot from DVD/USB

Follows a black screen, an Ubuntu logo, and finally, your new Ubuntu desktop appears.

Click `install` on the live desktop.

Choose your language in the welcome screen.

Choose your location.

Choose your keyboard layout.

Set up your disk partition.

Choose your username and password.

You’re now ready to install your new Ubuntu installation.

When the installation has finished, restart your computer (remove your DVD or USB). You’re now ready to begin using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu is not that hard but there are some stuff you need to have before you can install it to your laptop. You will need a USB thumb drive(or a CD). The thumb drive should have at least 2 GB capacity. I will be listing the steps needed for installing using a USB drive. I also recommend you take a backup of all your important data in some external hard disk or thumb drive.

First of all you need to download the right .iso file. You say that you are not a "techno geek" so I would recommend you to download Ubuntu 14.04. This version will be supported until sometime in April 2019. Th other version is supported for a much shorter period of time. I am assuming that you would prefer not to go though the trouble of updating your laptop too many times.

You also need to get the right architecture for your laptop. You are saying that your laptop currently runs 32-bit windows and has 2 GB RAM so I would recommend you to get the 32-bit version of Ubuntu. You can download the 32-bit version of Ubuntu from [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). You have to choose the 32-bit version from the drop-down list.

Once you have the correct .iso file. Head over to [this site](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) to download the bootable USB creator tool. Once it has downloaded run the program. Now just follow the steps in [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to create the bootable USB drive.

- Select Ubuntu from the drop-down list
- Choose the correct .iso file you have downloaded
- Click create
- Wait

Once you have prepared the USB drive, shut down your laptop and conect the USB drive to one of its ports. Now switch it on and boot to the USB.

Once Ubuntu has booted, you will have two options. "Try Ubuntu" and "Install to Disk". If you want to try running Ubuntu before installing it, click the "try Ubuntu" button. This will allow you to use Ubuntu without making any changes to your Laptop. If you like what you see, you can install Ubuntu. There will be an icon on the desktop for installing Ubuntu. Just double-click the icon to start the installer.

Now all you have to do is follow the instructions shown in the installer. Its a fairly simple process to install the Ubuntu OS.

I hope this answers your questions and hope you enjoy your time using Ubuntu.