# Unstable wifi connection in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on Asus R510J

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, 64-bit, broadcom

I have recently upgraded to 14.04 64-bit and since then my connection to my home WiFi network has become unstable, the computer often randomly disconnects and the ping commands often indicates loss of packages.

This is a major issue for me especially because I use many webapps as replacements for programming and productivity desktop apps.

My computer is an Asus R510J, I have another computer that runs Windows 8 which has no problem with my home WiFi network, the same goes for my tablet and my smartphone. Also, I brought my Ubuntu 14.04 Asus computer at work and there it had no problem with the WiFi connection.

Here is my WiFi info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 15 Jun 2015 22:52 CEST +0200

Booted last: 15 Jun 2015 22:10 CEST +0200

Script from: 21 May 2015 09:10 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-40-generic #54~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 10 17:30:45 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7


##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6605]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI
```

Comment: another interesting fact is that when i bring my personal laptop to work, i have no wi-fi unstability issue, it works perfectly

Comment: Have you tried installing any relevant drivers?

Comment: Did you move anything around at home (if so, put it back)?  Did you have customized wireless hardware settings to boost power/range (these would need to be redone)?

Comment: @thesdog yes i did, it didn't chage anything

Comment: @Daniel for both questions i did not do anything of that sort

Comment: Try upgrading to 15.04.  There may have been a bug fix for that.

Comment: Disregard the comment to upgrade to 15.04 as [15.04 is a STS and 14.04 is an LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) and [provide more information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) on your Wireless set-up.  Please [edit] your question to provide the contents of `wireless-info.txt`