# Does Ubuntu support my PC?

Tags: hp, bios

Hello folks i would like to know if my PC will support Ubuntu or Debian, and yes i know that there are alot of questions about it but mine is let's say special because is AMD Hardware and yeah i'm a gamer, i will leave my Dxdiag(using win8.1, gonna upgrade to win10 but i feel that my PC is going to crash) just need a backup plan :D.

Cheers! hope get some help from the Linux community. 
Dxdiag:https://mega.nz/#!6goXUIRa!-WofPhkQrY81k1n3yIDK1daBySzSt55Ag4qZe3M2NsU

Comment: [Here's](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/dmi/4458/dmi%3AAMDA8-6410APUwithAMDRadeonR5Graphics/) a list of all the laptops with your specs that are fully Certified for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model should be fully compatible without issue 
[Certified For Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/dmi/4458/dmi%3AAMDA8-6410APUwithAMDRadeonR5Graphics/)

Comment: Thank you! both answers @A1 Computers & Fabby are pretty useful :D now i dont fear installing Ubuntu as Backup plan. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Insert the Live DVD, choose "Try Ubuntu" and you'll know whether Ubuntu works or not.  All the other answers are make-belief.

Low quality queue reviewers: That's it!

Comment: And if this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Going to download Ubuntu 15 and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: If I were you [I'd try 14.04 LTS first](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) and only 15.04 if you run into incompatibilities as the former will be supported for much longer then the latter...  **;-)**