# Can't boot into Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04

Here is the bootrepair link , if someone can help I would totally appreciate it thanks. http://paste.ubuntu.com/12105065/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed Ubuntu in MBR boot mode (aka "BIOS") and Windows in UEFI mode. Both are mutually exclusive.  So you should delete Ubuntu and install it in UEFI mode, or delete Windows and install that in MBR mode.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.*

(I've deleted Windows for more then a year now an am running on [Ubuntu 14.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe))

Comment: Ok I will try to delete Ubuntu and re-install it in UEFI mode , thank you

Comment: @AnthonyDickerson: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: No problem , So how can I remove Ubuntu ? I can't boot into BIOS or from a disc , is there a tutorial online somewhere maybe!?

Comment: You need to read the documentation of your specific hardware (which you didn't even mention) as all UEFI systems are different for each vendor...  **:/**

Comment: I'm using a Toshiba Satellite C55-A 6gb ram 700gb HDD,  I'm new to linux  bear with me please.

Comment: And I have a Siemens laptop, so I can't help you... The best you can do is go to http://superuser.com and ask there if someone has the same laptop as you and still has the manuals. (or go to the Toshiba website and try finding the UEFI manual there and look through it

Comment: maybe you could help me figure out how to boot a usb I hit F2 and it boots straight into Ubuntu