# upgrade ubuntu to the latest released version

Tags: upgrade, updates

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu to the latest version.My ubuntu release when i run the `lsb_release -a` is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

But i think this is not the latest version of the Ubuntu released on the Ubuntu site.when i exec `sudo update-manager -d`i get nothing to update!
How can i upgrade my system to the latest version without losing any application or data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: **Please** have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) *before* you upgrade!!!  **:-)**

Comment: 14.04 is the latest LTS version. It is not a brilliant idea to upgrade to a non-LTS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upgrade to the latest version you would first have to upgrade to 14.10 and then to 15.04 !

This probably may result in some issues - you should consider a clean install of Ubuntu  15.10.

... and by the way ... it will be much faster ...

Comment: No you don't need that! You can do `dist-upgrade`