# Ubuntu 15.04 - setup the headphone volume to 100% not speaker volume to 100%

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Ubuntu 15.04 is used in a call-center. Where they are using this PC

[image]

Agent have random headphone to listen audio, so they connect or unplug the headphone in the Asus speaker output jack.

The moment they put the headphone jack unplug Ubuntu over-smartly put the headphone volume level to 0% and puts speaker volume level to 100%.

How can i tell Ubuntu to stop doing this auto settings? and freeze it as following setting? So that the headphone is plugged or not plugged i do not care, my setting remain frozen to headphone only?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Support for Ubuntu 15.04 ended on Feb 4 2016 so it's now off-topic here too!  **:-(** If you don't like upgrading often, [read this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe)

Comment: I upgraded into new version now. can you please instruct for the new version how to setup the headphone volume to 100% as frozen?

Comment: What version did you upgrade to?  I'm still on 14.04 Long Term Support, so if that, I can help you further.

Comment: YES - i have 14.04 too, 15.10 too, 14.10 too, what-ever you can show i can then interpret it into my 15.04 or 15.10.

Comment: OK, What's the output to ` lsb_release --short --codename&&uname --kernel-release`  and `alsactl --version`?

Comment: Sir, `wily && 4.2.0-16-generic` and `alsactl version 1.0.29`

Comment: Its killing my project, as its running in call-center people do not want to open terminal and do command line arguments, they want cake like Windows OS. please advise, how to make the headphone volume level to 100% (in your way, then i can migrate into my versions).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35366/discussion-between-dn-kaq-rw-and-yumyumyum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable the "**automute**" control that you see in Alsamixer:
use right arrow arrow key to move to this control,
then down arrow key to disable "automute":
   your speaker should now be independent from headphone jack,
 and only controlled by the "speaker" fader  (mute it).