# Ubuntu 15.10 with Windows XP on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-xp

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit and Windows XP in VirtualBox.
The virtualization start but in Windows XP there is no connection.

In Wbuntu I'm using the Ethernet connection from Vodafone Station.

The settings are:

[image: VirtualBox network configuration 1]

[image: VirtualBox network configuration 2]

[image: VirtualBox configuration overview]

What I must do to navigate in windows?

**Edit**

I tried in Windows to ping through `cmd.exe` and it works!
So the problem may be in Internet Explorer...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but **support for Ubuntu 15.04 ended on 4-Feb-2016**, so it's off-topic here too.  Please [read this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install-what-is-the-difference-betwe) how to avoid this in the future and [look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) for upgrade instructions.

Comment: Now i have ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Try to delete the host-only adapter unless you need it for something. This could be a dns problem, try to configure a manual dns on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved that way:

1. setting NAT in virtual machine
2. in Windows

   - run:

     ```
     netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
     netsh winsock reset
     ```
   - open windows firewall -> Advanced -> uncheck "local network connection (LAN)"
   - disable windows firewall
3. open explorer and download Firefox.

Comment: As you're a reputation 3 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"! Your own answer seems like a better candidate for the accepted answer since the currently accepted answer only gives general advice.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a VirtualBox NAT network. Your network is already NATting to the Internet, so you don't need to do this.

To make VirtualBox present your VM to the LAN as a normal everyday computer, in the Network settings, choose "Bridged Adapter" and bind it to your real PC's ethernet card. This way the VM is seen on the LAN as a "real" computer and will receive an IP address like any normal PC.

And yes, upgrade yourself to Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: update to 15.10 but internet connection still doesn't work on win.