# Which Release Of Ubuntu should I prefer ? (16.04 or 17.04)

Tags: updates

I am new to Ubuntu and I do not know which version of Ubuntu should I prefer.

Comment: There is no 17.01 release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decide what version of Ubuntu to install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install) or [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 16.04 is a "long term support" release that is supported with security updates through April 2021. Ubuntu 17.04, though newer, will only be supported through January 2018.

If you want an operating system that you can install and keep for years, and that you will not need to upgrade to a newer version in the next 8 months or so, stick with 16.04.

If newer features are more important to you and you're comfortable with needing to upgrade your system in a few months, feel free to use Ubuntu 17.04. (As someone else pointed out, there is no Ubuntu 17.01).