# NVIDIA display issue with brightness control and video playback

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, brightness

I noticed this problem with the NVIDIA proprietary driver on each and every upgrade of Ubuntu versions. Can I remove the prop driver and manage with the generic open source driver?

Comment: Related Meta page: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17983/250300

Comment: Here is [an example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572628/how-do-i-decide-what-version-of-ubuntu-to-install) Ask a question and then answer it yourself.

Comment: I posted your solution as a [community-wiki](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) answer below. Feel free to repost it as your own answer to get the reputation related to it. Then @-mention me in a comment to this question, so I can delete the community-wiki answer. @WinEunuuchs2Unix I finally found a way to phrase the beginning of the question as an actual question, so it’s converted to Q&A now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solution was initially posted by the OP as a [part of the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1031541/1).*

To remove the NVIDIA drivers completely

```
sudo apt purge ^nvidia
```

Some of the additional components which may raise issue need to be removed

```
sudo apt purge bumblebee vdpauinfo vulkan-utils
```

The removed and the pending dependencies can be fixed by installing the Ubuntu Desktop

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

In some versions of Ubuntu the xorg config will create some issue so it needs to be removed. If not found it will be well and good.

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Now make nouveau the default driver

```
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

If nouveau was blacklisted it is advisable to remove the blacklist

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

This the last and the final step of the process

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

Reboot the computer and check the brightness controls and the video playback.

Comment: OP has now posted their the answer themselves.

Comment: @TRiG And removed again… :-(

Comment: Odd. Very odd. I wonder why.