# Ubuntu 20.04 – freeze when trying to leave suspend mode

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend, freeze

On one of my computer, sometimes, when I try to leave suspend mode, I only get a dark screen, while the keyboard and the mouse do not respond. Still, I can log to this computer using SSH and then shut it off using `poweroff`, but this is annoying. Here is what I get in `journalctl` when this problem occurs:

```
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: Xorg: page allocation failure: order:5, mode:0x40cc0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: CPU: 8 PID: 3768 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P           OE     5.4.0-52-lowlatency #57-Ubuntu
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7B89/B450M MORTAR MAX (MS-7B89), BIOS 2.60 12/30/2019
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: Call Trace:
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  dump_stack+0x6d/0x9a
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  warn_alloc.cold+0x7b/0xdf
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xe34/0xe80
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  ? get_page_from_freelist+0x6b/0x390
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2d2/0x320
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  alloc_pages_current+0x87/0xe0
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  kmalloc_order+0x1f/0x80
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  kmalloc_order_trace+0x24/0xc0
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  __kmalloc+0x228/0x280
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  nvkms_alloc+0x24/0x60 [nvidia_modeset]
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel:  _nv002653kms+0x16/0x30 [nvidia_modeset]
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: WARNING: kernel stack frame pointer at 00000000e6b926bf in Xorg:3768 has bad value 000000004bbef540
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: unwind stack type:0 next_sp:0000000000000000 mask:0x2 graph_idx:0
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000064c84242: ffffa7abc3d8b8f8 (0xffffa7abc3d8b8f8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000bab3fe07: ffffffffae036ad2 (show_trace_log_lvl+0x20a/0x2ee)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a134ac46: ffffffffc202bc56 (_nv002653kms+0x16/0x30 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000dc3bf1a5: ffffa7abc3d8bc58 (0xffffa7abc3d8bc58)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000005c978840: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000061737179: 00000000c3d8b9e0 (0xc3d8b9e0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000036f6c85d: 0000000000000002 (0x2)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000004d68e2b6: 0000000000000001 (0x1)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000dbf45154: ffffa7abc3d88000 (0xffffa7abc3d88000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a5423d30: ffffa7abc3d8c000 (0xffffa7abc3d8c000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a74eac98: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008462ece5: ffffa7abc3d88000 (0xffffa7abc3d88000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009bb3b716: ffffa7abc3d8c000 (0xffffa7abc3d8c000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008c1eb915: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000005421fc80: 0000000000000002 (0x2)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009ddcfca8: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000601cdc56: 0000010100000000 (0x10100000000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000000ad5ff02: ffffa7abc3d8bc50 (0xffffa7abc3d8bc50)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c146800f: ffffa7abc3d8b810 (0xffffa7abc3d8b810)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000141e9207: ffffffffc202bc56 (_nv002653kms+0x16/0x30 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000003306c800: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000000ebe6596: 122e88f7f7367400 (0x122e88f7f7367400)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000efe52ed0: 0000000000000286 (0x286)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000006f6d9860: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009639281f: ffffa7abc3d8b9e0 (0xffffa7abc3d8b9e0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000005ef9e7ef: 0000000000040cc0 (0x40cc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000048c2291a: ffffa7abc3d8b908 (0xffffa7abc3d8b908)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000006592e5d: ffffffffae0366f5 (show_stack+0x35/0x50)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008d08a643: ffffa7abc3d8b928 (0xffffa7abc3d8b928)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c5f24da2: ffffffffaeaca7f3 (dump_stack+0x6d/0x9a)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b687cf13: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000007266102c: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000029d424ab: ffffa7abc3d8b9d0 (0xffffa7abc3d8b9d0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000832684f3: ffffffffae289fdd (warn_alloc.cold+0x7b/0xdf)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000153d8e65: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000583e230a: 00040cc001400100 (0x40cc001400100)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000007f2455ea: ffffffffaf381798 (.LC19+0x447/0xb3e)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000ffa884cc: ffffa7abc3d8b958 (0xffffa7abc3d8b958)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000040c2b534: 0000000000000018 (0x18)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000e0328d56: ffffa7abc3d8b9e0 (0xffffa7abc3d8b9e0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000002c648473: ffffa7abc3d8b978 (0xffffa7abc3d8b978)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008e663c42: 122e88f7f7367400 (0x122e88f7f7367400)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000082612c9b: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000005402f7ca: 00000001ae2871bb (0x1ae2871bb)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008242ba19: ffffa7abc3d8ba84 (0xffffa7abc3d8ba84)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008dbf193f: 0000000000000005 (0x5)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000089f9b05c: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b1e5f50c: 0000000000000002 (0x2)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000e01599b6: ffffa7abc3d8bb08 (0xffffa7abc3d8bb08)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000f7c63f68: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000048500b02: 0000000000000005 (0x5)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000043668b19: ffffa7abc3d8baf8 (0xffffa7abc3d8baf8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b9420e69: ffffffffae2885e4 (__alloc_pages_slowpath+0xe34/0xe80)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000545f7cb3: 00000050c3d8baa0 (0x50c3d8baa0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000056e0e57d: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000094191294: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000cd6ad507: 0000004000000004 (0x4000000004)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000065c8911f: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a3909c7a: 0000001000000800 (0x1000000800)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000743aac7f: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b1b8729e: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000506e2df7: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008e243e21: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000cb5628c1: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c32597d7: 0000000000000400 (0x400)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000002a813371: 00006d82e0caa240 (0x6d82e0caa240)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000008d0aaa5: 0000030100000000 (0x30100000000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000033cbfb11: 00000000000000cd (0xcd)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000946542c1: ffff927d1f355d00 (0xffff927d1f355d00)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000051223461: 0000024000000001 (0x24000000001)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c71c2fbd: ffffa7abc3d8baa0 (0xffffa7abc3d8baa0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000092dc5f0: 0140090000000000 (0x140090000000000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000033373900: 00040cc000000240 (0x40cc000000240)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000001c9b2842: 000000021f355d00 (0x21f355d00)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000171c1f2a: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000dd439453: 0000000000000301 (0x301)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000789067f2: 0000000000000301 (0x301)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000da6e3f6c: ffffa7abc3d8baf8 (0xffffa7abc3d8baf8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000007fcf8c20: ffffffffae2871bb (get_page_from_freelist+0x6b/0x390)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000002e9c1ed7: 00040cc011ee5a00 (0x40cc011ee5a00)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000003e0b8702: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000070c28bd: 0000000000000001 (0x1)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000007f23b56b: 122e88f7f7367400 (0x122e88f7f7367400)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000020eb5bf: 0000000000000005 (0x5)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000083fd6e28: 0000000000040cc0 (0x40cc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000077c6fe8e: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009148ec2f: 0000000000040cc0 (0x40cc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000068bf6ad5: ffffa7abc3d8bb60 (0xffffa7abc3d8bb60)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000462cdc6c: ffffffffae288902 (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2d2/0x320)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000002543ab40: ffff927d1f357080 (0xffff927d1f357080)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b738c184: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000005c4a7d97: ffff927d1f357080 (0xffff927d1f357080)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c100e53f: 0000000200000000 (0x200000000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000bf2ac81c: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000ff8bab7b: 122e88f7f7367400 (0x122e88f7f7367400)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009aa1fc20: 0000000000000001 (0x1)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000d8f72deb: 0000000000040cc0 (0x40cc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c999ff2d: ffffffffafcbbe40 (policy_zone+0x20/0x20)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000063852fa1: 0000000000000005 (0x5)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000f26085c1: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000f3716a44: ffffa7abc3d8bb90 (0xffffa7abc3d8bb90)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000003ca1f287: ffffffffae29ff27 (alloc_pages_current+0x87/0xe0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000004abf1b2d: 0000000000010110 (0x10110)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000acf6fb2e: 0000000000000005 (0x5)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a85d7d67: 0000000000000cc0 (0xcc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000091202a80: 0000000000000005 (0x5)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000f0b5827f: ffffa7abc3d8bbb0 (0xffffa7abc3d8bbb0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b57f950c: ffffffffae255f2f (kmalloc_order+0x1f/0x80)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000bbaa209f: 0000000000010110 (0x10110)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000090c98cdf: 0000000000010110 (0x10110)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c8970704: ffffa7abc3d8bbf0 (0xffffa7abc3d8bbf0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000ad91b424: ffffffffae255fb4 (kmalloc_order_trace+0x24/0xc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000056a281c2: 0000000000000301 (0x301)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000022437bed: 0000000000000001 (0x1)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000000194fe8: 0000000000010110 (0x10110)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000004bcaf195: 0000000000000cc0 (0xcc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000ef08a139: 0000000000010110 (0x10110)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000d9e37d06: ffff927cbd190008 (0xffff927cbd190008)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a9af4b7f: ffffa7abc3d8bc30 (0xffffa7abc3d8bc30)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000cf3a4c7f: ffffffffae2aed08 (__kmalloc+0x228/0x280)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000f2f925a8: 0000000000000003 (0x3)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000730e8e99: 0000000000000001 (0x1)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000063f45af7: 0000000000010110 (0x10110)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000089589061: 00007ffebedeb4e0 (0x7ffebedeb4e0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b43e6add: ffff927bce970008 (0xffff927bce970008)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000007bfd0ec: ffff927cbd190008 (0xffff927cbd190008)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c6266d31: ffffa7abc3d8bc50 (0xffffa7abc3d8bc50)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000007a71b94d: ffffffffc1fed394 (nvkms_alloc+0x24/0x60 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000207c5053: 0000000000010110 (0x10110)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000792315e6: ffff927cc725d108 (0xffff927cc725d108)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000e6b926bf: 0000000000000009 (0x9)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000003ddcd43e: ffffffffc202bc56 (_nv002653kms+0x16/0x30 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000005d5dae09: ffff927c93f74008 (0xffff927c93f74008)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000009f81199: ffffffffc2022e36 (_nv002759kms+0x66/0x1470 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000f741b84a: 0000000000040cc0 (0x40cc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000075aa43aa: ffff927a0a755b60 (0xffff927a0a755b60)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000006d8d284f: ffff927a0a750008 (0xffff927a0a750008)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000cf321732: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000003888ea67: ffff927c93f74008 (0xffff927c93f74008)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000c384b64c: ffffffffae29ff00 (alloc_pages_current+0x60/0xe0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009db0ed87: 00000000000062a8 (0x62a8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b3254e62: 0000000000000003 (0x3)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a690145e: 0000000000000cc0 (0xcc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000007a878db3: 0000000000000003 (0x3)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009c152c78: ffffa7abc3d8bce0 (0xffffa7abc3d8bce0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000009bb4ad6a: ffffffffae255f73 (kmalloc_order+0x63/0x80)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000007f151b2d: 00000000000062a8 (0x62a8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000ec283ef7: 00000000000062a8 (0x62a8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000077fb47d4: ffffa7abc3d8bd20 (0xffffa7abc3d8bd20)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000d50a0e5a: ffffffffae255fb4 (kmalloc_order_trace+0x24/0xc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000788ef9fb: 00007ffebedf3ae0 (0x7ffebedf3ae0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000005dee4b5e: 0000000000000001 (0x1)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000f40df50b: 00000000000062a8 (0x62a8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000000b11b5ba: 0000000000000cc0 (0xcc0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000093534d47: 00000000000062a8 (0x62a8)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000ebb9eb5f: ffffffffc1fefe30 (_nv000531kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000006fd72096: 0000000000000000 ...
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000000d8edfc2: ffff927d0cc07800 (0xffff927d0cc07800)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000002733d12f: 0000000000000003 (0x3)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000547d64dd: ffff927a0a755990 (0xffff927a0a755990)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000b262f532: ffffffffc1ff0341 (_nv000673kms+0x31/0xe0 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000071be960c: 00000008ae53b9ae (0x8ae53b9ae)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000095a33c70: ffffffffc20b4928 (_nv002237kms+0x288/0xfffffffffffdc960 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000020a2f0a4: 0000000000005b58 (0x5b58)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000be90e811: 0000000000000001 (0x1)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000762639c2: 0000000000000009 (0x9)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000ad1be7e2: ffff927cc725d108 (0xffff927cc725d108)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000003b32081d: 00007ffebedeb4e0 (0x7ffebedeb4e0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000044df0958: ffffffffc20b46a0 (_nv002166kms+0x78/0xfffffffffffdc9d8 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a6780822: ffffffffc1fefe30 (_nv000531kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000019cd221c: ffffffffc1ff1796 (nvKmsIoctl+0x96/0x1d0 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000e56009c9: ffff927a0a750008 (0xffff927a0a750008)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000009476ff6: 00000000000062a0 (0x62a0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000002eaf1d36: 0000000000000292 (0x292)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000043b5728: ffff927c778dcc00 (0xffff927c778dcc00)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000094284872: ffffa7abc3d8be10 (0xffffa7abc3d8be10)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000e7a2db6b: 0000000000000009 (0x9)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000056e8e081: 00007ffebedeb4e0 (0x7ffebedeb4e0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000003c1c3564: 00000000000062a0 (0x62a0)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 0000000099d32d1b: ffff927cbea36000 (0xffff927cbea36000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a41c5488: ffffffffc1fedf32 (nvkms_ioctl_common+0x42/0x80 [nvidia_modeset])
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 00000000a617386a: ffff927c6e858000 (0xffff927c6e858000)
oct. 23 18:17:40 petra kernel: 000000008bc8257a: ffff927c778dcc00 (0xffff927c778dcc00)
```

Well, it seems the problem is related to X.org and NVidia, which is consistent with the fact I get a dark screen and no response from keyboard and mouse. Therefore, I have tested what is suggested on NVidia website:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-suspend-resuming-and-wakeup-with-nvidia370-28/45282/9

But it did not change anything, therefore I have put my configuration back to its initial state. Now, I do not have a clue on how to solve this.

Here are some information concerning my configuration:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I use low-latency kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux petra 5.4.0-52-lowlatency #57-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 15 12:05:45 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ free -h
              total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:           15Gi       8,8Gi       247Mi       301Mi       6,6Gi       6,3Gi
Partition d'échange:        15Gi       2,2Gi        13Gi
```

```
$ sudo lshw -short
Chemin matériel            Périphérique  Classe         Description
======================================================================
                                            system         MS-7B89 (To be filled by O.E.M.)
/0                                          bus            B450M MORTAR MAX (MS-7B89)
/0/0                                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/f                                        memory         16GiB Mémoire Système
/0/f/0                                      memory         Project-Id-Version: @(#) $Id$Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: PO-Revision-Date: 2020-04-03 08:20+0000Last-Translator: Lyonel Vincent <Unknown>Language-Team: MIME-V
/0/f/1                                      memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchrone Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/f/2                                      memory         Project-Id-Version: @(#) $Id$Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: PO-Revision-Date: 2020-04-03 08:20+0000Last-Translator: Lyonel Vincent <Unknown>Language-Team: MIME-V
/0/f/3                                      memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchrone Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
/0/12                                       memory         512KiB L1 cache
/0/13                                       memory         4MiB L2 cache
/0/14                                       memory         32MiB L3 cache
/0/15                                       processor      AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
/0/100                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                                  generic        Starship/Matisse IOMMU
/0/100/1.1                                  bridge         Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.1/0                                storage        E12 NVMe Controller
/0/100/1.3                                  bridge         Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.3/0                                bus            400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller
/0/100/1.3/0/0              usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.3/0/0/1                            multimedia     Clarett 4Pre USB
/0/100/1.3/0/0/7                            input          Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
/0/100/1.3/0/0/a                            input          USB Laser Mouse
/0/100/1.3/0/1              usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.1              scsi0           storage        400 Series Chipset SATA Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.1/0            /dev/sdb        volume         3726GiB TOSHIBA HDWE140
/0/100/1.3/0.1/1            /dev/sdc        disk           1500GB WDC WD15EARS-00M
/0/100/1.3/0.1/1/1          /dev/sdc1       volume         1397GiB Volume EXT4
/0/100/1.3/0.1/0.0.0        /dev/cdrom      disk           BW-16D1HT
/0/100/1.3/0.2                              bridge         400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge
/0/100/1.3/0.2/0                            bridge         400 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/0/0                          bridge         XIO2000(A)/XIO2200A PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge
/0/100/1.3/0.2/0/0/0                        bus            XIO2200A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
/0/100/1.3/0.2/1                            bridge         400 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/1.3/0.2/1/0          enp35s0         network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1.3/0.2/4                            bridge         400 Series Chipset PCIe Port
/0/100/3.1                                  bridge         Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/3.1/0                                display        GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
/0/100/3.1/0.1                              multimedia     GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX]
/0/100/7.1                                  bridge         Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/7.1/0                                generic        Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
/0/100/8.1                                  bridge         Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/8.1/0                                generic        Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
/0/100/8.1/0.1                              generic        Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
/0/100/8.1/0.3                              bus            Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0            usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/0/2                          multimedia     HD Webcam C510
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1            usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/1          scsi11          storage        Expansion Desk
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/1/0.0.0    /dev/sda        disk           4TB Expansion Desk
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/1/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1       volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/1/0.0.0/2  /dev/sda2       volume         3725GiB Volume EXT4
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3          scsi10          storage        USB3.0 Card Reader
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.0    /dev/sdd        disk           USB3.0 CRW-CF/MD
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.0/0  /dev/sdd        disk           
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.1    /dev/sde        disk           USB3.0 CRW-SM/xD
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.1/0  /dev/sde        disk           
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.2    /dev/sdf        disk           USB3.0 CRW-SD
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.2/0  /dev/sdf        disk           
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.3    /dev/sdg        disk           USB3.0 CRW-MS
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.3/0  /dev/sdg        disk           
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.4    /dev/sdh        disk           USB3.0 CRW-SD/MS
/0/100/8.1/0.3/1/3/0.0.4/0  /dev/sdh        disk           
/0/100/8.1/0.4                              multimedia     Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
/0/100/8.2                                  bridge         Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/8.2/0                                storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/8.3                                  bridge         Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/8.3/0                                storage        FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/14                                   bus            FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                                 bridge         FCH LPC Bridge
/0/101                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/102                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/103                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/104                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/105                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/106                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/107                                      bridge         Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/108                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 0
/0/109                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 1
/0/10a                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 2
/0/10b                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 3
/0/10c                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 4
/0/10d                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 5
/0/10e                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 6
/0/10f                                      bridge         Matisse Device 24: Function 7
/0/1                                        system         PnP device PNP0c01
/0/2                                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/3                                        system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/4                                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/5                                        printer        PnP device PNP0400
/0/6                                        communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/7                                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
```

Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: Did you instal NVIDIA driver?, Installing the nvidia driver would solve this issue. Possibly this link may help you https://askubuntu.com/a/1046139/383075

Comment: Well, I do use the NVidia proprietary driver:

$ aptitude search nvidia-driver-450
i   nvidia-driver-450               - NVIDIA driver metapackage                 
p   nvidia-driver-450-server        - NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage

Comment: I had the same problem, After installing the NVIDIA driver everything was resolved, except brightness control, later I modified the configuration file to get it done. The reason I shared the link was to remove the unsuccessful installed NVIDIA driver. The guide to install NVIDIA was explained in detail https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Well, thank you, but once again, I was using NVidia proprietary driver and had no problem to install it, but I have this problem with suspend mode. I have tested with the standard kernel, but the problem persisted. Right now, I am testing Nouveau, I will see if the problem is still there.

Comment: You are welcome and keep posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with the standard kernel, but the problem persisted. So I uninstalled the proprietary driver and used Nouveau. It turned out that it fixed the problem. Furthermore, I tested some 3D visualization code that I did, I did not notice any slowdown problem and I did not see any CPU overload–these codes also do some numerical computations, so they use a lot of CPU, therefore I probably would have seen an overload if there had been some. I have also tested a video editing software and likewise it seems that the graphics card fully supports decoding. Also, I can use Wayland instead of X.org, when the proprietary driver still does not allow it. I have not been able to test computations on graphics card yet.

When my video card was new, the performance of Nouveau was lagging behind the proprietary driver. Now that the card is less recent, it seems that Nouveau performances compete with proprietary driver performances.

In any case, my observation is that NVidia slows us down in the progress of the graphics server. If you have the choice, I think it is better to prefer ATI processors. If you have a NVidia processor, if it is not too recent, it is worth trying Nouveau.

In any case, the problem is solved.