# Ubuntu on Conputers

Tags: motherboard

I want to try Ubuntu due to frustrations I am encountering with Windows 10. Which computer with hardware components is best suited to run  Ubuntu.
I will be very glad to know the best.
Thanks!

Comment: See [How do I decide what version of Ubuntu to install?](https://askubuntu.com/q/572628/295286) and [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/295286).  There's also [certified Ubuntu hardware page](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The Recommended Minimum System Requirements, here, should allow even someone fairly new to installing Ubuntu or Gnu&Linux to easily install a usable system with enough room to be comfortable. A good "rule of thumb" is that machines that could run XP, Vista, Windows 7 or x86 OS X will almost always be a lot faster with Ubuntu even if they are lower-spec than described below. Simply try Ubuntu CD as a LiveCD first to check the hardware works.

Ubuntu Desktop Edition
2 GHz dual core processor
2 GiB RAM (system memory)
25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: I would have preferred this answer if you've provided your source for specs (which I believe was https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements which I know because I was a recent editor of that document which won't apply to many readers).  Also given I believe your answer is copy/pasted, I'd preferred you to have used "quotes"  so we can see what is your belief/experience and that which you sourced elsewhere.

Comment: Source of comment is now in body of comment!