# Ubuntu Software Center unable to launch with 16.04

Tags: software-center

Good evening !

I already used Ubuntu 14.04 (why are all versions in .04?) I am unable to launch Ubuntu software. It only blinks for a second before shutting the window down. Here is a screenshot of the (rather) empty window it displays :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using apt to reinstall it?
`sudo apt install --purge --reinstall software-center`

(also .04 appears to be [date related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233/whats-the-meaning-of-version-numbering-of-ubuntu))

Comment: Before doing what you asked me to, I did my usual `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and it solve my problem... thank you anyway !