# Unable to download Modelio on 16.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I have to use modelio for a project management course which requires to draw graphs. Yet, even from the [website actual download page](https://www.modelio.org/downloads/download-modelio.html) when I try to launch it, it crashes. I don't know if this is because Ubuntu Software Center crashes too ([for which I asked a separate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877075/ubuntu-software-center-unable-to-launch-with-16-04)) because I was able to to download and run PhpStorm...

Here is the file I downloaded from their website :

```
modelio-open-source-3.6.0_amd64
```

Here are informations about my computer bit version

```
:~$ uname -i
x86_64
```

Here is a picture of the Ubuntu Software Center before clicking on install which leads the window to shut down :

[image]

I tried Liso's answer and got :

[image]

Comment: Can you try this and report back the output errors ? (Assuming your downloaded file is in your Downloads folder)  : sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/modelio-open-source-3.6.0_amd64

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using terminal, then theres workaround for this problem. Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> combination, assuming the file located on `Downloads` directory:

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/modelio-open-source-3.6.0_amd64
```

Followed by `-f` command to fix any dependencies problem:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Please note this as reference to other similar problem, as Ubuntu Software aren't reliable to download `.deb` files outside than Official repositories.

Comment: I tried but get an unexpected `No such file or directory| error.

Comment: @Marine1, you need to specify the *correct* path to the DEB file you downloaded.