# Where can i download ubuntu 20.05 or 20.06

Tags: system-installation

Where can i download ubuntu 20.05 or 20.06 ,as this is not listed in any ubuntu official websites

Comment: Ubuntu (desktop and server) uses *year.month* (e.g. 20.04 mean 2020 April). Knowing that there are only 2 releases per year, April and October, your question is totally nonsensical.

Comment: They aren't listed as there are no such releases.  As already stated; Ubuntu's main products are released in April (.04) & October (.10), though in 2020-June the Ubuntu Core 22 product was released; it's a *snap* only product so uses the *year* format instead of *year.month*, and *dailies* are produced but they use a *yyyymmdd* format on the included date; but the filename is not unique (metadata & files inside only contains the encoded release). Dailies can actually produced multiple times per day; the second will have a .1 added to it...

Comment: In 2006, the release wasn't read in April, but was instead released in June - thus the Ubuntu release of 2006-June was Ubuntu 6.06 LTS; but that's an exception; No release before or since has been outside of April or October.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of version numbering of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233/whats-the-meaning-of-version-numbering-of-ubuntu)

Comment: yes  i am able to understand  thanks  but our client has this version in their on prem and we need migrate to azure so not able to understand how he has downloaded or using that version

Comment: "our client has this version in their on prem " presumably not a standard ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

These versions do not exist. There are two releases per year, denoted with 0.4 for the April release and .10 for the October release. Every two years, a spring release comes with long term support (LTS). The current release, 22.04, is an LTS release, and so is 20.04 and 18.04. Other releases are interim releases with 9 month support. See [details](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) here.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 6.06 LTS existed**.

In 2006, the release wasn't ready in April, but was instead released in June - thus the Ubuntu release of 2006-June was Ubuntu 6.06 LTS; but that's an exception; No release before or since has been outside of April or October.

As already stated (*prior answer & comment(s)*); Ubuntu's main products are released in April (.04) & October (.10).

There some *specialist* releases, eg. in 2022-June the Ubuntu Core 22 product was released; it's a *snap* only product so uses the *year* format instead (ie. it has 22 for the year 2022, without *month*).

There are also *dailies* produced but they use a *yyyymmdd* format on the included date; but the filenames are **not** unique (metadata & files inside only contains the encoded release). Dailies can actually produced multiple times per day; the second will have a .1 added to it...  They are for QA-testing though, and not officially *released* products.